# Angular UI router - not calling the views

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying out Angular UI router for the first time. I'm having issues where the views are not being called accordingly. Check the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cBfR6u2BPJvKN16vi6hG?p=preview

Does anything stand out on the router?

```
deviceApp.config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('devices', {
            views: {
                'environment': {
                    template: 'Look I am a view!',
                    controller: 'DataCtrl'
                },
                'devicedetail': { 
                    templateUrl: 'index.html',
                    controller: 'DeviceCtrl'
                }            

            }
        }
   )}
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps the absence of a "url" definition in your view object?

```
'environment': {
                    url: '/environment',
                    template: 'Look I am a view!',
                    controller: 'DataCtrl'
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

**config.js**

```
  .config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
  })
```

**app.js**

```
state('main', {
    url: '/',
    views: {
      '': { templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html', controller: 'MainCtrl'},
      'navbar': { templateUrl: 'components/navigation/navbar/navbar.html'},
    }
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
  <header ui-view="navbar" class="header"></header>
  <section class="content">
     <div ui-view></div>
  </section>
</body>
```